# I want to access the foreign key and filtering queryset in django-admin

Tags: django-admin, django-queryset

I want to access the foreign key and filtering in djnago-admin

How can i filter 'objects' in django-admin?

I want to filter based on the patient's name and date. However, i think it seems that it should be filtered based on the input value in admin.

as you know, In general api, when FE throws a value, BE filters based on it in database. But, I don't know what to do alone in admin.

tell me bro...!

it's my model

```
class PayHistory(TimeStampedModel):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    package_patient = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    created_time = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)

class PayHistoryChange(TimeStampedModel):
    payhistory = models.ForeignKey(PayHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    history_patient = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    ...
```

```
@admin.register(PayHistoryChange)
class PayHistoryChangeAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "branch",
        "history_patient",
        "history_cancellation_method",
        "history_cancellation_amount",
        "history_reapproval_method",
        "history_reapproval_amount",
        "change_reason",
        "history_manager",
    )
    class Media:
        js = (
            'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js',
            'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedm2m.js',
        )

    def history_patient(self, request):
        objs = PayHistory.objects.filter(package_patient="history_patient", created_time=) #I don't know this !!
```

Comment: I understand you want to filter the choices? If so, check this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133455/django-limit-choices-to-doesnt-work-on-manytomanyfield)

Comment: okay thx. i will find it