# Error filtering filter_horizontal field. The error is : store.models.variation_price.product.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: variation_price has no product

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am working on a Django project which has models shown below. I'm trying to filter filter_horizontal field in admin.py.

In models.py:

```
class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def color(self):
        return super(VariationManager,self).filter(variation_category='color', is_active=True)
    
    def sizes(self):
        return super(VariationManager, self).filter(variation_category='size', is_active=True)

variation_category_choice = (
    ('color', 'color'),
    ('size', 'size'),
)

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation_category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=variation_category_choice)
    variation_value = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    objects = VariationManager()


class variation_price(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In admin.py of project, I have:

```
class variation_priceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = variation_price
        fields = ['price','product','variations','is_active']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(variation_priceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['variations'].queryset = Variation.objects.filter(product=self.instance.product)

@admin.register(variation_price)
class variation_priceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = variation_priceForm
    filter_horizontal = ('variations',)
    list_display = ('get_variations', 'price', 'stock','id','is_active')
    list_editable = ('is_active',)
```

I'm getting an error for this line of code above:

```
self.fields['variations'].queryset = Variation.objects.filter(product=self.instance.product)
```

It says:

```
store.models.variation_price.product.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: variation_price has no product
```

Is there a way to select the product first and then add the variation_price?
Thanks. Any help is appreciated