# Need help with Django ModelForm: How to filter ForeignKey/ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Alright, I'm having a hard time explaining this, let me know if I should fill you in on more details.

My url looks like this: http://domain.com/`<category`>/
Each `<category`> may have one or many sub categories.

I want the category page to have a form with a select box (among other fields) containing the category sub-categories. 
I've currently hard coded the form in one of the templates, but I want to make it reflect the model directly.

In my currently hard coded solution, I have in my category view:

```
s = Category.objects.filter(parents__exact=c.id)
```

that the form template iterates through and prints out the select box (see model code below)

I'm guessing I want a ModelFormSet with an **init** that filters out the categories, but I can't seem to find how to do it in the docs.

Been looking at [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform) as well, but I can't get it to work properly.

#### My models

```
# The model that the Form should implement
class Incoming(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    zipcode = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# The categories, each category can have none or many parent categories
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self',symmetrical=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### My form

```
class IncomingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Incoming
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would edit Daniel Rosemans reply and vote it winner, but since i cant edit it i will post the correct answer here:

```
class IncomingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Incoming

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IncomingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['cat_id'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(
                    parents__exact=self.instance.id)
```

The difference is **self.fields['cat_id']** (correct) vs *self.fields['parents']* (wrong, we both made the same mistake)

Comment: i am getting error here undefined variable instance. And when i use self.instance.id i am getting "none". what wrong i am getting i dont know.

Answer (score 9):

As you say, you need a modelform class with a custom `__init__`:

```
class IncomingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Incoming

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IncomingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['parents'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(
                                              parents__exact=instance.id)
```

Comment: I juuuust managed to get it to work! I had almost had exact your code, but it refused to work :)
It should say self.fields['cat_id']... :)

Comment: i am getting error here undefined variable instance. And when i use self.instance.id i am getting "none". what wrong i am getting i dont know.