# Django: Admin inline forms initial data for every instance

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been reading a lot but I don't seem to be able to figure out a solution to this.

I'm writing an application in Django, I'm still writing the admin side.

I have a model called "Environments" and a model called "Servers", there is a ForeignKey relation between Servers and Environments such as a given Environment has several servers.

When modifying the "add" form for Environments in the admin interface I use a Inline form to be able to visualize the list of Servers that will be associated to the Environment, something like this:

```
class ServerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Server
    extra = 39

class EnvironmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ServerInline]
```

Pretty simple right?

What I would like to do is prepopulate the Servers inline forms with default values, I've been able to prepopulate them with the same value doing this:

```
class ServerInlineAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Server

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServerInlineAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['name']='Testing'

class ServerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ServerInlineAdminForm
    model = Server
    extra = 39

class EnvironmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ServerInline]
```

But this isn't what I want, I  would like to be able to initialize the 39 Server form instances with 39 different values that I have in a list. What would be the best way to do that??

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that I solved the problem myself and hadn't answered here.

What I finally did is to override the Environment class save_model method instead for using the admin forms.

I'll explain a little bit better:

I have an environment object and a server object. An environment has a number of servers that are linked to it via a foreign key into the server object. My goal was to populate the servers associated to an environment in the environment creation process. To be able to do that what I did was override the save_model method for the Environment object, do an obj.save() and AFTERWARDS create the Server objects that point to this environment, and then obj.save() again. Why afterwards? Because I can't relation a new created server with an environment that doesn't exist yet. Let me know if there is someone interested on he actual code.

Comment: I am interested in code. `Environment.save()` method does not seem to take info about `Server` instance(s) via its arguments

Answer (score 14):

This is an old answer, a much simpler solution has become possible since, see jnns's answer with `get_formset_kwargs`.

---

Here is my implementation, [thanks to Steven for the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392201/236195).

All in **admin.py**:

```
class SecondaryModelInline(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = SecondaryModel
    formset = SecondaryModelInlineFormSet

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super(SecondaryModelInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        formset.request = request
        return formset

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        extra = super(SecondaryModelInline, self).get_extra(request, obj, **kwargs)
        something = request.GET.get('something', None)
        if something:
            extra = ... figure out how much initial forms there are, from the request ...
        return extra
```

Someplace before, also in **admin.py**, this:

```
class SecondaryModelInlineFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = SecondaryModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondaryModelInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        if self.request.GET.get('something', None):
            # build your list using self.request
            self.initial=[{'field_a': 'A', ...}, {}... ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure exactly why you want to do this, but perhaps you could create a modelformset:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet
class ServerFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServerFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial = [{ 'name': 's1', }, {'name': 's2'},] # supply your list here
```

and set this on your inline:

```
class ServerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ServerInlineAdminForm
    model = Server
    extra = 39
    formset = ServerFormSet
```

I have not tried this out.

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.formset

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset

Comment: This work fine after made some fixes to the code: **1.** Use `BaseInlineFormSet` instead `BaseModelFormSet` and **2.** set `initial` before call `__init__`: ,`kwargs.update({'initial': [{ 'name': 's1', }, {'name': 's2'},]})`, set `self.initial` after super call `__init__` not works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Since Django 4.0, the `ModelAdmin` has a method  `get_formset_kwargs` that can be used for exactly this scenario with very few lines of code:

```
class ServerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Server

class EnvironmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ServerInline]

    def get_formset_kwargs(self, request, obj, inline, prefix):
        formset_params = super().get_formset_kwargs(request, obj, inline, prefix)

        if not obj.id and isinstance(inline, ServerInline):
            formset_params |= {"initial": [
              {"name": f"Testing {i}"} for i in range(39)
            ]}

        return formset_params
```

Please note: the dict merge operator `|` is only available from Python 3.9 onwards. Use `dict.update()` on older versions.

Comment: This is what I need but unfortunately we are one version behind.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but since the extra forms generated are essential Django Formsets, what you need to do is bind initial data to the formset which is explained in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset).

I just read through the docs and it looks like you can [define your own formset inside your inlineadmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.formset) and then as mentioned above, prepopulate the formset with data from your list. I think you could achieve that by placing the prepopulation code in your class' **init** method.

I know this isn't a very elaborate explanation but I found the question interesting and looked up the docs and thought maybe I could point you in the right direction with what to try next.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I wanted to comment on frnhr's answer, but did not have enough reputation, so:

The answer worked for me, I just needed to loop through the forms in the formset and set the initial data for each of them:

```
class SecondaryModelInlineFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = SecondaryModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondaryModelInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        if self.request.GET.get('something', None):
            # build your list using self.request
            for form in self:
                form.initial = {'field_a':'A',...} #This is what I changed
            self.initial=[{'field_a': 'A', ...}, {}... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in case of prepopulating `user` from `request.user` for `StackedInline` and `TabularInline`.

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    for form in formset.forms:
        form.instance.user = request.user
    formset.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `initial` elements in the inline class as all the other answers suggest **won't be enough to actually get the elements saved**.

Django [ignores the initial elements](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59f475470494ce5b8cbff816b1e5dafcbd10a3a3/django/forms/models.py#L946-L947) that were not modified by users, so you need to add some extra logic to your `InlineFormSet` to save the initial data:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import BaseInlineFormSet

class InitialElementsInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.initial_extra is not None:
            self.extra = len(self.initial_extra)

    def save_new_objects(self, commit=True):
        super().save_new_objects(commit)
        for form in self.extra_forms:
            if not form.has_changed() and form.initial in self.initial_extra:
                instance = form.instance
                instance.__dict__.update(form.initial)
                setattr(instance, self.fk.name, self.instance)
                self.new_objects.append(instance)
                if commit:
                    instance.save()

        return self.new_objects
```

This Formset class is doing two things:

- In the `__init__` method, we're setting the initial form number to be the same as your initial elements, so all of them are displayed.
- When the form is submitted, it saves the elements that weren't modified. Be careful with this: if you didn't supply all the required fields in `initial`, it will fail to create the object, resulting in a Server Error response.

Once you have created this class, you should be able to use it in your admin models like this:

```py
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    formset = InitialElementsInlineFormSet

    def get_initial(self, request):
        data = [
            {
                "field_a": "example",
                "user_id": request.user.id,
                "favorite_number": i,
            }
            for i in range(3)
        ]
        return data

class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyModelInline]

    def get_formset_kwargs(self, request, obj, inline, prefix):
        formset_params = super().get_formset_kwargs(request, obj, inline, prefix)

        if isinstance(inline, MyModelInline) and obj.pk is None:
            formset_params.update(initial=inline.get_initial(request))

        return formset_params
```

Override the Inline class' `get_initial` method to populate the forms you want to see when creating a new object. You can access the user object as well as data from the parent using the `request` object.

In the `ParentAdmin` class, we're making sure we only populate the initial keyword for our `Inline` class. By checking if `obj.pk is None`, we ensure this happens only during the **creation** of a `Parent` object. You shouldn't need to modify this part.