# Django formset initial data - how to specify values for ForeignKeyFields?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, foreign-keys, django-admin

I'm successfully initialising the values of the field `Ip` using a custom inline `FormSet`:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/24462173/129805
class PrepopulatedIpInlineFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Ip

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PrepopulatedIpInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        apn_ggsns = ApnGgsn.objects.all()
        initial = []
        for apn_ggsn in apn_ggsns:
            print apn_ggsn.cidr
            cidr = IPNetwork(apn_ggsn.cidr)
            print cidr
            for ip in cidr:
                # skip .0 and .255 addresses
                ipstr = str(ip)
                print ipstr[-2:]
                if ipstr[-2:] == '.0' or ipstr[-4:] == '.255':
                    continue
                print ipstr
                num = Ip.objects.filter(ip=ipstr).count()#, apnid=apn_ggsn.apn_id, ggsn_id=apn_ggsn.ggsn_id).count()
                if num == 0:
                    initial.append({'ip': ipstr, 'apn': apn_ggsn.apn, 'ggsn': apn_ggsn.ggsn})
                    break
        self.initial = initial
```

The `ip` field is being correctly populated on the admin form with the next free ip address.  Multiple inline forms/objects are being generated correctly.

I cannot get the `<select>`s to show the correct initial values.

I have tried each combination of adding a `_id` suffix to the dictionary key and using the actual object and the object's id as the value.

The `<select>` boxes never show an initial `selected` value.

The documentation shows examples, but not of `ForeignKeyField`s.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a browser refresh bug.  When I opened the page a new tab, it all worked as expected.