# Django admin save related model, change extra and prepopulate inline fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I'm creating a Django application based on Django admin app, I spend lot of time to do a task but no success, I wish someone gives me advises to accomplish my work:

I have an *admin parent model* and two *related models admin*:

```
class FirstChildModelAdmin(admin.TabulareInline):
    model = FirstChildModel
    # ...

class SecondChildModelAdmin(admin.TabulareInline):
    model = SecondChildModel
    # ...
class ParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ParentModel
    inlines = [FirstChildModelAdmin, SecondChildModelAdmin]
    # ...
```

In the admin change_view, if I click on *Save and contiue editing* button I need to generate multiple inline forms for the `SecondChildModel` (by overriding `InlineModelAdmin.get_extra` method)

So, in my  **admin.py** I tried to create my custom formset for the `SecondChildModelAdmin`, as explained here [Admin inline forms initial data for every instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384973/django-admin-inline-forms-initial-data-for-every-instance?answertab=active#tab-top), but did not reach what I want.

This my custom formset:

```
class CustomModelInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = SecondChildModel

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomModelInlineFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print("custom formset")
    if 'files' in kwargs:
        # Here some code to retrieve files content

        self.initial = [{'fiedl_one': 'some_content', 'fiedl_one': '...'}, {....}]
```

This is my question:

How can I generate multiple inline forms of the `SecondChildModel` and populate his fields from content files selected on `FirstChildModel`? Is it possible to do that?

I will appreciate any helps

Thanks

Comment: I think something like that is what you are looking https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I'm looking