# How to make only the 1st inline object boolean field "True" by default only for "Add" page in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django-models, boolean, django-admin, default

I'm trying to make only the 1st inline object boolean field `True` by default only for **Add** page.

So, I have `Person` model and `Email` model which has the foreign key of `Person` model as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_used = models.BooleanField()
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Then, I set the custom form `EmailForm` to `form` in `EmailInline()` as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['initial'] = {'is_used': True}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class EmailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Email
    form = EmailForm # Here
    
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

But, all inline objects are `is_used=True` by default on **Add** page as shown below:

[image]

And, I added one main object with one inline object which is `is_used=True` as shown below:

[image]

But, the added inline object and other not-yet-added inline objects are `is_used=True` on **Change** page as shown below:

[image]

And, I added one main object with one inline object which is `is_used=False` as shown below:

[image]

But, the added inline object and other not-yet-added inline objects are `is_used=True` on **Change** page as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I make only the 1st inline object boolean field `True` by default only for **Add** page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Admin inline forms initial data for every instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384973/django-admin-inline-forms-initial-data-for-every-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global variable `count` in `__init__()` and overridden [get_formset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_formset) and set `EmailForm` to `self.form` in overridden `get_formset()` as shown below to make only the 1st inline object boolean field `True` by default only for **Add** page:

```py
# "admin.py"

count = 0 # Here
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global count
        if count < 1:
            kwargs['initial'] = {'is_used': True}
            count += 1
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class EmailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Email
    
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if not obj:
            self.form = EmailForm
        global count
        count = 0
        return super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

Then, only the 1st inline object is `is_used=True` by default on **Add** page as shown below:

[image]

And, I added one main object with one inline object which is `is_used=True` as shown below:

[image]

Then, only the added inline object is `is_used=True` on **Change** page as shown below:

[image]

And, I added one main object with one inline object which is `is_used=False` as shown below:

[image]

Then, the added inline object and other not-yet-added inline objects are `is_used=False` on **Change** page as shown below:

[image]

In addition, if changing `count < 1` to `count < 2` as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

count = 0
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global count
        if count < 2: # Here
            kwargs['initial'] = {'is_used': True}
            count += 1
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# ...
```

Then, the 1st and 2nd inline objects are `is_used=True` by default on **Add** page as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This can break quite easily with concurrent access.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Because of it uses the global variable `count`?

Comment: Yes, assume two (or more) users make a request at about the same time. One possibility is the reset to 0 causes other users to have multiple `True` defaults, while another possibility is that a user never gets a `True` default since the other user already caused the `count` to increment. Global variables are quite prone to race conditions.