# Django ModelForm instance with custom queryset for a specific field

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I have a model not unlike the following:

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    made_at = models.ForeignKey(Factory)
    added_on = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
```

All users may work at a number of factories and therefore their user profiles all have a `ManyToManyField` to `Factory`.

Now I want to construct a `ModelForm` for `Bike` but I want the `made_at` list to consist of only factories at which the current user works. The idea is that users should be able to add bikes that they've assembled and enter which of the factories the bike was made at.

How do I do that?

Comment: And, for what it is worth, your question is more readable and to the point than the one I have pointed as a dupe...

Comment: @celopes: Do you have any source on that?

Comment: Nah... I even deleted the comment where I said it was about to get deprecated. For some reason I had my mind that it was. I think I read a ticket about it... But the docs have it there, and there is no sign of deprecation in the source. Just ignore me. :-) And it is `auto_now_add` btw.

Comment: Here is the ticket where I read `auto_now_add` was to be deprecated: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6434. But ignore it because nothing in the code says it is...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You question might be a [dupe of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform).

[S. Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform/291968#291968) there is the ticket to solve your problem.
He answered:

> ForeignKey is represented by django.forms.ModelChoiceField, which is a ChoiceField whose choices are a model QuerySet. See the reference for ModelChoiceField.
>
> So, provide a QuerySet to the field's queryset attribute. Depends on how your form is built. If you build an explicit form, you'll have fields named directly.
>
> `form.rate.queryset = Rate.objects.filter(company_id=the_company.id)`
>   If you take the default ModelForm object, `form.fields["rate"].queryset = ...`
>
> This is done explicitly in the view. No hacking around.

Answer (score 49):

try something like this in the view

```
form  = BikeForm()
form.fields["made_at"].queryset = Factory.objects.filter(user__factory)
```

modify the Factory queryset so that it identifies the factory which the user works at.

Answer (score 0):

Nowaday, you should use:

```
    form.base_fields['alumno_item'].queryset = AlumnoItem.objects.prefetch_related(
        'alumno',
        'alumno__estudiante',
        'alumno__estudiante__profile',
        'item'
    )
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct.  It means you are modifying the form at the wrong time (not from the view).