# Django dynamic model choice forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form like so:

```
class ThingSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    things = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Product.objects.filter(product=my_product),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None,
    )
```

My question is - how do I pass in the `my_product` variable when a page loads? Should I create a custom `__init__` method?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just was working on something like this today.  I found [this to be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821289/django-modelform-instance-with-custom-queryset-for-a-specific-field).  It's the answer from Dave

models.py

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    made_at = models.ForeignKey(Factory)
    added_on = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
```

view.py

```
form  = BikeForm()
form.fields["made_at"].queryset = Factory.objects.filter(user__factory)
```

I did mine with a filter(foo=bar) type query.

Then in the forms.py

```
made_at = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Factory.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can override the **init**

```
    class ThingSelectionForm(forms.Form):
        things = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect,
            empty_label=None,
        )
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
              my_prod = kwargs.pop('my_prod), None
              super(...)
              self.fields['things'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(product=my_prod),

#view

form = ThingSelectionForm(my_prod = my_prod)
```