# Override django form's clean method to change the ModelChoiceField queryset

Tags: django-forms, overriding

I have this model:

```
class PetAttribute(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(PetSpecies, related_name = "pets")
    pet_category = models.ForeignKey(PetCategory, related_name = "pets", blank=True, null=True)
    pet_type = models.ForeignKey(PetType, related_name = "pets", blank=True, null=True)
    additional_fields= models.ManyToManyField( AdditionalField, null= True, blank=True )
```

Now i want to add an additional option in select (pet_category, pet_type), which is

> ("0","Other")

in queryset of these. I have tried but form give me an error

> Error: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281195/forms-modelchoicefield-queryset-extra-choice-fields-django-forms) is a one solution of it, but i want to do this by **ModelChoiceField**

Any suggestion?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible, are you sure this is what you want to do? You are telling a field that validates choices to the model objects to accept a non-valid answer.

Creating an "other" PetType and PetCategory object or using `empty_label` as "other" might make more sense than forcing the ModelChoiceField to accept arbitrary values.

Then to find objects with "other" selected, query for None,

```
pattrs_w_other_pet_type = PetAttribute.object.filter(pet_type=None)
```

Comment: thanks for replying .... Sir is there any way, i can override the clean method and to allow this "Other" option. basically when user select other option from choices then i want to fill him a text field, which will dynamically shown to user, after selecting this "other" option this text field will be mandatory to fill... so please help me in this case..