# Django : Use widget to limit choices in a ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, widget

My model form inherit from subsystem form.
I want to limit choices for the user in the form. (specially the name)
I know I have to use widgets. But It doesn't work.

I have to use SubsytemForm.

```
SUBSYSTEM_CHOICES = (a1,a2,a3)


class Subsystem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=20)


class SubsytemForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Subsystem
        widgets = {
            'name': ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=SUBSYSTEM_CHOICES)
        }
```

Comment: What are `a1`, `a2` and `a3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [django model forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/):

> If you explicitly instantiate a form field like this, Django assumes
>   that you want to completely define its behavior; therefore, default
>   attributes (such as max_length or required) are not drawn from the
>   corresponding model. If you want to maintain the behavior specified in
>   the model, you must set the relevant arguments explicitly when
>   declaring the form field.

You can try with:

```
class SubsytemForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    name =  forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices= choices )
    class Meta:
        model = Subsystem
```

Also you can

```
class SubsytemForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = Subsystem
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_choices = kwargs.pop('name_choices', None)
        super(SubsytemForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].queryset= self.name_choices
```

and send `name_choices` as parameter in `SubsytemForm` creation. Remember that choices should be a query set.

Also, you should read [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Comment: Choices should *not* be a queryset if the OP is using `forms.ChoiceField`. Choices needs to be a tuple of key/value pair tuples. Only if the OP were using `forms.ModelChoiceField` should they use a queryset.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, thanks about your comment. I mean that in second scenario, where name is a modelChoiceField, choices should be a query set. You agree? Please, be free to fix my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`SUBSYSTEM_CHOICES` is not a valid value for the `choices` attribute because it has no key/value pairs. You need something like:

```
SUBSYSTEM_CHOICES = (
    (a1, 'a1 Display'),
    (a2, 'a2 Display'),
    (a3, 'a3 Display'),
)
```