# Reduce number of choices in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an `IntegerField` with choices.

The list of choices consists of 10 different choices. I have different `ModelForm` using this integerfield.

In some of the modelforms I don't want to display all of the choices.

Can I in the ModelForm reduce the number of available choices?

Comment: Are you talking about a `django.forms.IntegerField` or a `django.db.models.IntegerField` ?

Comment: A `django.db.models.IntegerField` with `choices=[(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),...]` from which I want to choose only some of the choices

Comment: Seen this yet?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434011/django-use-widget-to-limit-choices-in-a-modelform

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new form class that is a subclass of `ModelForm`. Then the `__init__` method of the `ModelForm` class change one of the things in `self.fields` after calling the superclass constructor.