# How to set queryset or limit or filter in ManytoManyField

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

Hello all here I am new in Django till now I worked with simple models and generic views.

Now I have two models, `Server` and `InventaryGroups`, where `InventoryGroups` is group of `Servers`.

```
class Server(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    ip2 = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    ssh_key = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    last_login_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_login_from = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + " - " + self.name

class InventoryGroups(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    host = models.ManyToManyField(Server)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_hosts(self):
        if self.host:
            hostlist = []
            for name in self.host.all():
                hostlist.append(name)
            return hostlist

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + " - " + self.name
```

What I am trying to do is limit my `Server` (server list) according to `User`. Like this:

[image: Admin example]

You can see all servers in hostlist. 
But I want to show only those `Severs` which are added by authenticated users or users selected in `InventoryGroups.user`

Comment: What you want is a `ModelForm` that allows you to customize the queryset used for the `ForeignKey` widget. There's a fair bit of material on SO about that. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform) looks like what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin I got solution to filter choices i just added just one line in my form `host = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=InventoryGroups.objects.filter(user_id=1))`

But I still have one issue that i want to set user_id to currently logged in user, I need code something like this, 
    `host = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=InventoryGroups.objects.filter(user_id=(self.request.user.id))`

Comment: See the example in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form).

Comment: Thank you very much @kevin finally i resolved my issue