# Django form how to show logged in user only?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django model "Post" that has a field:

```
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

I also have a PostForm in forms.py with author as a field and Post as the model. I want to only show the user logged in and not all superusers.

https://gyazo.com/fb8884391bdf8284065175fbcdc16f75

Is there a painless way of doing so? If not what is my best option?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform

Comment: You will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a high level, you'll need to handle it in the `__init__` method of the form. After you call super, change the queryset on the `author` field of the form and set it to the request's user.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I guess I am a little confused, may be overthinking it.