# Django filter choices in ForeignKey field in a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How can I filter the options shown for a ForeignKey field in a Model Form?

I tried to follow this thread [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform) but I'm pretty new to Django and I got very confused.

I have an app for Users (with a UserManager/AbstractUser models, not relevant)

Another app for:

- Products, with product_id and product name,
- Purchases, with product_id and user_id.

Another app for Tickets, with a form to open a ticket.

In that form I want to show only the products that the user has bought, so the user can only open a ticket for the products he has.

Code below, I've removed non relevant fields, etc.

Ticket Model

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
   ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tickets')
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', related_name='tickets')
```

Ticket ModelForm

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['subject', 'reason', 'product']
```

Product & Purchase Models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    ...


class Purchase (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='purchases')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    ...
```

New Ticket Form view

```
def new_ticket(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        ticket_form = TicketForm(request.POST)
        ...

        if ticket_form.is_valid() and comment_form.is_valid():
            ticket = ticket_form.save(False)
            ticket.user = request.user
            ticket.save()
            ...
            return redirect(reverse('ticket-detail', args={ticket.pk}))
    else:
        ticket_form = TicketForm()

    args={'ticket_form':ticket_form}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'tickets/ticket_form.html',args)
```

In the template I use {{ ticket_form }} within the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any other suggestion/explanation? 
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Simply lookup all purchases made by the user by mapping the `user` foreign key. Once you will have the purchases, you will also have the corresponding products.

```
user = 'your user object here'
purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(user=user)
products = [purchase.product for purchase in purchases]
```

now your `products` list is a list of objects of the purchases made by the user. If you want the name of the purchases, just add the line:

```
product_names = [product.name for product in products]
```

where `product_names` is a list of the names of the product bought by the particular user.

Comment: Thanks dartvader1996, that make sense, but where do I use that code? 

In the Model? That is built with the products object, and I suppose I can't do things like this there. 

In the ModelForm? I thought there I just say what fields I want from the model. 

In the view ticket_new? That's probably to late as the form is already being shown.

Thanks!

Comment: The tricky part for me is that I need this filter/query for a field in the form.