# Showing Many-To-Many in different model's form in Django?

Tags: python, django

Say I have three models, a `Professor` model, a `Course` model, and a `Review` model. The user is allowed to make a `Review`, which reviews a `Professor` that teaches a certain `Course`.

I'm thinking of how to model the many to many relationship of `Professor` and `Course`, and how to reference that relationship in `Review`. My idea so far is to use `models.ManyToMany` to link `Professor` and `Course`.

Models.py (Prof)

```
class Prof(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = False)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    prof = models.ManyToManyField(Prof)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Models.py (Review)

```
class Review(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length = 4000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        default = 5, 
        validators = [MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    prof = models.ForeignKey(Prof, related_name = 'reviews')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name = 'reviews')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'reviews')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.message
```

forms.py

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    rating = CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number','value': 5, 'min': 0, 'max': 5}))

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['message', 'rating', 'prof', 'course', 'user']
```

This is my code so far for displaying the form

```
<h1>New Review</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ review_form.message }}</p>
    <p>{{ review_form.rating }}</p>
    <p>{{ review_form.prof }}</p>
    <!-- The prof chosen's courses should be shown here -->
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Right now, `forms.py` shows all the objects under `Course`, and i'm not sure how to instead show the courses of a professor. Is it possible to filter the form after a prof is chosen from the drop down, to display the courses he/she teacher?

Comment: It is possible to filter the courses by professor, but not during template generation. You would need to make an AJAX call to the server and return a filtered course set.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're going about this the right way.  You haven't mentioned your urls.py structure yet, or `views.py` but the most straightforward way to do this is to display the courses by professor, taking the professor's `id` (or slug-field) in as a parameter  - either in the URL (v straightforward) or as the output from a form on a previous page (and reload the template with a professor parameter) or in Ajax, depending on your appetite for shiny-new-things.

In your view, when you call the form, you can then do, along the lines from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291968/1293222) -

`form.courses.queryset = Course.objects.filter(professor__in=[professor.id,])`

Note that I've put filtered on a list here, which only has one item - it does give you scope to expand, or to use a queryset for more complicated functions later.

Tweak as appropriate if you're using class-based views. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try and implement this, and get back to you. (Hopefully with an accept this as answer haha)