# Django: How to obtain current user in CreateView and filter a ForeignKey select field based on this

Tags: django

I am creating an expense submission system, which will be multi-user.

For the purpose of this question, there are two models: `Claim` and `Journey`.  A user creates a claim and each claim can have multiple journeys.  I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/0e75f04b2f7693a7aa27e6e214fce4af) of the code snippet as it's quite long.

In this snippet, I have sucessfully:

- Made `ClaimListView.get_queryset` filter by current user, so whoever's logged in can only see a list of their own claims.
- Made `ClaimCreateView.form_valid` set the correct user when the form is submitted.
- Made `ClaimDetailView.get_queryset` filter by current user.  If someone tries the url for another user's claim detail, they get a 404 (perfect!)
- Done the same as above for `JourneyListView`
- Done the same as above for `JourneyDetailView` - again 404 if not authroised :D

However, when I access `JourneyCreateView` via the URL, the dropdown box for `claim` still shows claims for the other users.

[image: dropdown box]

How should I filter the user within the `JourneyCreateView` class, so that the `claim` field only shows claims assigned to the current user?

The closest to a solution I've got is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1244586/2052575) which suggests overriding the `__init__` function in the `JourneyForm` which would leave me with this:

```
class JourneyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Journey
        fields = ['date', 'distance','claim']

    def __init__(self,alloweduser,*args,**kwargs):
        super (JourneyForm,self ).__init__(self,*args,**kwargs) # populates the post
        self.fields['claim'].queryset = Claim.objects.filter(tech_id=alloweduser)
```

However I'm not sure how to pass the `alloweduser` in from `JourneyCreateView` or, more to the point, obtain the current user in this class.

`form_valid` isn't any use in this case, as I'm trying to obtain the user prior to the form being submitted.

Comment: You can access the `request` object with `self.request`. So the user is stored in `self.request.user`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In views, the request the view is handling is stored in `self.request`, so you can obtain the user with `self.request.user`, and its `id` with `self.request.user.id`.

A Django view with the [**`FormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#formmixin) has a method that can be overwritten to pass parameters: [**`get_form_kwargs()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs).

So we can implement this as:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class JourneyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Journey
    form_class = JourneyForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['alloweduser'] = self.request.user.id
        return kwargs

    # ...
```

Comment: Do you know if anything need to be changed to pass this `alloweduser` back to `JourneyForm`, as with this code edit I get the error **'JourneyForm' object has no attribute 'get'**

Comment: Dang, the error was in my code, as per: [this](https://snakeycode.wordpress.com/2016/02/29/django-error-form-object-has-no-attribute-get/).  This is perfect, now the dropdown only shows the logged in user.