# Is there a simple way to create Chained Dynamic Drop Down List in Django Admin Site?

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, cascadingdropdown

At this moment I am creating a project to learn how to use django. In this project there are three models:

- Category
- Subcategory
- Product

And what I'm trying to achieve is to dynamically choose the corresponding subcategory after selecting the category, and thus be able to add the product.

- I tried to use smart_selects without results, since it is not compatible with python 3.7
- I tried to filter the list of subcategories using the selected category field as a filter, without success, I think I am not formulating the code well, so that it takes the value of the category field to filter the list of subcategories dynamically.

This is my code:

*models.py*

```python
"""Z"""
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    """Z"""
    category_name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        """Z"""
        return self.category_name

class Subcategory(models.Model):

    """Z"""
    subcategory_name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)
    subcategory_parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, verbose_name="Parent", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)
        verbose_name = "Subcategory"
        verbose_name_plural = "Subcategories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory_name

class Product(models.Model):
    """Z"""
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        Subcategory, verbose_name="Subcategory", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        product_name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)
        verbose_name = "Product"
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __str__(self):
        """Z"""
        return self.product_name
```

*admin.py*

```python
"""Z"""
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Subcategory, Product

class SubcategoryInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """Z"""
    model = Subcategory
    extra = 1

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Z"""
    inlines = (SubcategoryInline,) 

@admin.register(Subcategory)
class SubcategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Z"""

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Z"""
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "subcategory":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Subcategory.objects.filter(subcategory_parent=request.category)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

And this is the error that is shown when I'm trying to use it:

```
AttributeError at /admin/prototype/product/add/

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'category'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/prototype/product/add/
Django Version:     2.0.9
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'category'

Exception Location:     C:\asp\pilgrim\prototype\admin.py in formfield_for_foreignkey, line 30
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.0
Python Path:    

['C:\\asp\\pilgrim',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\lisandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 1 Jan 2019 11:48:18 -0400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass a filtered queryset to a custom form that you use in the admin (or in a particular view/template, if you're trying to do this in the real frontend). See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/291968/11295291