# Pass variable from view to form in Django

Tags: python, django

I am building a simple task management system, where a Company can have multiple projects, and each company has employees. I want a form that allows managers to add users to projects, with the constraint that the available users belong to the company.

I am passing the variable company_pk from the view to the form, but I am not sure how to set/access the variable outside the **init** finction.

```py
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, company_pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Intantiation service.
        This method extends the default instantiation service.
        """
        super(AddUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if company_pk:
            print("company_pk: ", company_pk)
            self._company_pk = company_pk

    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.filter(company__pk=self._company_pk))
```

```py
form = AddUserForm(company_pk=project_id)
```

As mentioned, I want to filter the users to only those belonging to a given company, however I do not know how to access the company_pk outside of **init**. I get the error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Do you have your models set up correctly with foreign keys?

Comment: I think so; I have project.users as ManyToMany and project.company as ForeignKey

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, company_pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(company__pk=company_pk)

    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I had to modify my views.py method a little:

form = AddUserForm(project.company.pk, request.POST)

Answer (score 0):

You must use self.fields to override the user's queryset

```
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, company_pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if company_pk:
            self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(company__pk=company_pk))
```

for more information about it. check this out [How to dynamically filter ModelChoice's queryset in a ModelForm](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/questions/2017/03/22/how-to-dynamically-filter-modelchoices-queryset-in-a-modelform.html)