# Django create form field with a model of the current user

Tags: python, django

I have a simple app, where a user has multiple businesses, and each business has multiple products, what I´m trying to do is a make product creatView, where i can select a business from the ones owned by the current user. I tryed editing the **init**() method of the **ModelForm** like this:

```
class Producto_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Producto_Model
        fields = ("Nombre_Producto","Negocio","Descripcion_Producto",'Precio_Producto','Tags',"Foto")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Producto_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Negocio'].queryset = Negocio_Model.objects.all().filter(Administrador_id=kwargs['user'].id)
```

and then i changed the get_form_kwargs from the create product view like this:

```
class crear_producto(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    template_name = "tienda/crear_producto.html"
    form_class= Producto_Form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tienda_app:crear_producto')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('register_app:logIn')

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform/1244586#1244586) question but I keep getting the error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`

Answer (score 0):

So everything is almost fine but you must pass the user variable to the form init as the kwargs, also, on the queryset dont call it like `kwargs['user']` and just call user, something like this:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Producto_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Negocio'].queryset = Negocio_Model.objects.all().filter(Administrador_id=user.id)
```

also I changed the super() constructor on the `get_form_kwargs`like this:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(crear_producto, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```