# Limit Django ModelForm ForeignKey choices depending on request.user

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-generic-views

It is sometimes desirable to restrict the choices presented by the `ForeignKey` field of a `ModelForm` so that users don't see each others' content. However this can be tricky because models do not have access to `request.user`.

Consider an app with two models:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Content(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The idea is that users can create folders and content, but may only store content in folders that they themselves created.

*i.e.:*

```
Content.folder.user == request.user
```

**QUESTION:** How can we use for example `CreateView`, so that when creating new content users are shown the choice of only their own folders?

Answer (score 1):

I do this by overriding `CreateView.get_form_class()` in order to modify the attributes of the relevant field of the form before it is passed to the rest of the view.

The default method, inherited from `views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin`, returns a ModelForm that represents all the editable fields of the model in the `base_fields` dictionary. So it's a good place to make any desired changes and also has access to `self.request.user`.

So for the above example, in views.py we might say:

```
class ContentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Content
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_form_class(self):
        modelform = super().get_form_class()
        modelform.base_fields['folder'].limit_choices_to = {'user': self.request.user}
        return modelform
```

Read more about `ForeignKey.limit_choices_to` in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Note that field choices are enforced by form validation so this should be quite robust.

Answer (score 0):

The following mixin looks automatically limits the choices for all foreign key fields that point to a model that has a user field:

```
class LimitForeignKeyChoicesToSameUserMixin:

    def get_form_class(self):
        this_model_has_user_field = False
        choice_limited_fields = []
        for field in self.model._meta.get_fields():
            if isinstance(field, ForeignKey) or isinstance(field, ManyToManyField):
                if field.name == 'user':
                    this_model_has_user_field = True
                elif hasattr(field.related_model, 'user'):
                    choice_limited_fields.append(field.name)
        form_class = super().get_form_class()
        if this_model_has_user_field:
            for field in choice_limited_fields:
                form_class.base_fields[field].limit_choices_to = {'user': self.request.user}
        return form_class
```

And then I use the following base class for all 'add' views:

```
class AddViewBase(LoginRequiredMixin, LimitForeignKeyChoicesToSameUserMixin, 
                  CreateView, FormMixin):
    slug_url_kwarg = 'id'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And this base class for 'edit' views:

```
class EditViewBase(LoginRequiredMixin, LimitForeignKeyChoicesToSameUserMixin,
                   UpdateView):
    slug_url_kwarg = 'id'
    slug_field = 'id'
```