# View dropdown by condition Django Model Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have a model of categories with a title

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

I have another model with many to many field of categories

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=CASCADE)
    Category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Both my models got a user foreign key.

I created a product form using django modelforms.

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

The issue I face is that I get the category of another user also. how to show only categories of that particular user? so that one user won't see another user's category

Comment: rae you rendering the page with a function based view or class based view ?

Comment: @DrayenDörff Function based view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Comment: @TrueGopnik That problem solves in the case of Foreign key, but I have Category field as manytomany field

Answer (score 3):

=========== views.py =============

```
def HomeView(request):
  form = ProductForm(user_id=request.user.id)
  context = {
    'form':form
  }
  return
```

render(request,'index.html',context)

========= form.py ===============

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user_id is not None:
            self.fields['category'].widget = forms.Select(choices = Category.objects.filter(user=user_id).values_list('title','title'))
        else:
            self.fields['category'].widget = forms.Select(choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('title','title'))
        
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

=============== models.py ===============

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

==== Output when user not logged in the display all categories ====

[image]

==== Output when user one logged in the display category1,category2 ====

[image]

==== Output when user two logged in the display category3,category4 ====

[image]

======== admin panel category model ===========

[image]

Comment: Brother, I really appreciate the time you took to answer my question. The problem is that, I have a manytomany category field in a product. so one product can have multiple categories. Giving a foreign key made me to choose only one, how to fix that issue?

Comment: please check the second answer I think your requirement fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

================================================

**with MultiSelect choices**

================================================

======= form.py ========

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user_id is not None:
            self.fields['category'].widget = forms.SelectMultiple(choices = Category.objects.filter(user=user_id).values_list('title','title'))
        else:
            self.fields['category'].widget = forms.SelectMultiple(choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('title','title'))
        
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

======= views.py =========

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .form import *

def HomeView(request):
  form = ProductForm(user_id=request.user.id)
  context = {'form':form}
  return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

========== html ===========

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
     Index | Page 
{% endblock title %}
   
{% block body %}
  <h1>Current user : {{request.user}}</h1>
  <hr>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock body %}
```

======== modals.py ==========

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

=========== screenshot ouput ===========

[image]

[image]

[image]